# Get dll minimal and maximal stack address

Tags: c, dll, stack

I scan a process memory by injecting dll and read it's memory. The problem is that I also reads the memory of the dll stack's. Does someone know how to fix this? ( not get min and max addresses of dll)

Comment: DLLs don't have a stack, only threads do.

Comment: So they save their local parameters on the process stack?

Comment: There is also no `process stack`. Each thread has its own stack.